# Send a POST request and open a response Html with ionic-native/in-app-browser?

Tags: angular, ionic2, inappbrowser

I was trying to send a post to a web page from Ionic Cordova using in-app-browser plugin.
Below is the Postman request

```
POST /home/about HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:14548
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8ff8f2d8-d7e6-3465-ae28-832541817c60

{
 "Name":"My Name",
 "DateTime":"19/19/19"
}
```

This request needs to render the response html as well.
I could open a web page with the below.

```
const browser = this.iab.create('https://www.myurl.com','_self',{location:'no'});
```

Is this possible? If so How can I post to a page with `ionic-native/in-app-browser` ?

Comment: I too have the same requirement. If you had found any solution on this please help me with that. thank you

Comment: @Saif Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for that.
There were work around using angular universal.
But nothing seemed a solid approach..Sorry